# date calculation in laravel model

Tags: laravel

I want to return values in my model based on dates but not sure how to?

## Logic

calculate the date that post has published + 7 days after that and return true or false.

## example

Let say I want add `new label` in posts from the date that post published till 7 days after that, and in the day 8th that `new label` be removed.

**How do I do that?**

## Update

I ended up with something like this in my model currently

```
public function isNew($query){
        return $query->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
    }
```

but it returns `Undefined variable: isNew` in my blade.

please give me your suggestions.

Comment: There's lots of ways to do that.  Can't you just add a isNew() method and check if the published date is less than 7 days old?

Comment: @Devon i want to do that not sure how to calculate it that why

Comment: You could use [nesbot\carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) check the current day, then If label is less than now, minus 7 days, remove label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

thanks for all the helps I solved my issue with code below:

```
 public function getisNewAttribute(){
        $now = Carbon::now();
        return Carbon::parse($now) <= Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->addDays(7);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you make use of Carbon:

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

That link should help a lot but to point you in the correct direction, you should be able to do a comparison:

I assume you DB date is held in ISO (Y-M-D, eg: 2019-01-07)

```
$date= Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dateFromDB);
if($date->diffInDays(Carbon::now() < 8){
    Code for Add Label here
}
```

Or if you are using timestamps:

```
$date= Carbon::createFromTimestamp($dateFromDB);
if($date->diffInDays(Carbon::now() < 8){
    Code for Add Label here
}
```

Comment: database date is as default (timestamps) i will update my question,,,,

Comment: Check you haven't missed a ; in the code to be executed if the condition is true

Comment: this is my code `public function isNew(){
        $date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($this->created_at);
        if($date->diffInDays(Carbon::now() < 7){
            //
        }
    }`

Comment: and one thing as my text is static and i just use this `isNew()` for validation in my blade like `@if($isNew()) NEW @endif` how can i avoid your code second part? i don't want to put any extra code in there is just for validation purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Are labels stored in a separate table from your posts?  You could use 'effective dating'.  Have indexed 'show_at' and 'hide_at' fields in your labels table.  Have entries there get created as soon as the post does.  You could use database triggers to do this, or model observers.  And when querying for all labels related to a given post, make sure they're between those dates (or those dates are null).

For a more simple solution, you could do a `whereRaw('CURRENT_DATE <= DATE_ADD(dateFieldName, INTERVAL 7 DAY)')`.  If timezones are a factor, you could use the `CONVERT_TZ()` function, though it's generally good practice to store everything in UTC to avoid those issues.

Comment: no the label is static text `new` i just want to show this text from the date that post published till 7 days after that. probably carbon way is the best i just not sure how to?

Comment: If you're looking for a Carbon solution, I think Petay87 has the right answer.  But you lose the benefit of being able to filter your results prior to making your script digest them.  Actually though, it sounds like what you _might_ be looking for is a Model Accessor, which contains that carbon logic and resolves the field to a boolean based on that condition: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators

Comment: yes something like Model Accessor, and i don't need filter for them this is not that beneficial for me is just is good to have some label and let users know which post is new you know? :)